# How to set the jslint ES6 directive in Brackets?

Tags: javascript, jslint, adobe-brackets

I get this error: "expected an identifier and instead saw 'const'", I'm using brackets text editor. I found this answer: "You need to specify the es6 directive. See JSLint Help". But I can't figure it out how to specity the es6 directive in brackets. 
Here's my code:

```
const singleQuotes = '<p>Single quotes</p>';
const doubleQuotes = "<p>Double quotes</p>";
const stringLiterals =  `<p>String literlas</p>`;

const result = singleQuotes + doubleQuotes + stringLiterals;
document.querySelector('.basic').innerHTML = result;
```

I appreciate any help. It works fine if I use var.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**One File**

If I remember right, you put the following at the very top of your file:

```
/*jslint es6:true*/
```

**Project Wide**

If you want all files in your **project** to abide ES6, you can add a `.brackets.json` file to the root of your project.

**Brackets Wide**

If you want all files to abide ES6, you can modify your User-global preferences by clicking the following menu items: `Debug -> Open Preferences` and then adding the `jslint.options` property to your preferences.

See [How-to-Use-Brackets: Preferences](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences) for more information.

---

However, I just tried to do this with my Brackets installation with all extensions disabled and Brackets doesn't understand the directive.  I think Brackets has a very old version of jslint installed by default.  You may want to use some extensions to try to supplement the old version.

What I ended up doing was installing the [brackets-jshint](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/brackets-jshint) and changing my brackets preferences file to use jshint by default with the following option:

```js
{
    "language": {
        "javascript": {
            "linting.prefer": [
                "JSHint"
            ],
            "linting.usePreferredOnly": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a comment at the top of the file like this, [as documented in JSLint Help...](http://www.jslint.com/help.html#directives)

```
/*jslint
    es6
*/

const singleQuotes = '<p>Single quotes</p>';
const doubleQuotes = "<p>Double quotes</p>";
const stringLiterals = `<p>String literlas</p>`;

const result = singleQuotes + doubleQuotes + stringLiterals;
document.querySelector('.basic').innerHTML = result;
```